# Moving an object in list to the front of the list

Tags: c#

Newbie here, I have a list

```
 @Model.Cleaners
```

If  when going through the list

```
bool something = true
```

I want this item to move and now be the first item in the list (so it will show up first.)
I tried this

```
 @foreach (var c in Model.Cleaners)
                {
                    var item = c;
                    @Model.Cleaners.Remove(c);
                    @Model.Cleaners.Insert(0,item);
                 }
```

But I am getting an error Cannot convert type 'void' to object' What does that mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: I'm 99.9% positive you will get the answer if you google 'Cannot Convert Type Void to Object C#'

Comment: You can probably achieve what you want with an `OrderBy` instead of actually shuffling your items, have a look at this http://www.vitoshacademy.com/c-linq-where-orderby-select/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way to do it, but in the past when confronting this problem I did the following.

I added a nullable int to the database table, then I made a foreach loop and depending on whatever qualifications I wanted on top I gave a lower number. Then I did orderby.

The advantage of doing it like this is you have a lot of flexibility in your order. You can give 3 values 0, 1, and 2.

example

```
  @foreach (var c in Model.Cleaners)
 {
c.ConfirmationChecker = 1;
foreach (var p in c.TimeConfirmations)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        c.ConfirmationChecker = 0;
    }


}
}
```

Then afterwards you can do orderby

```
  @foreach (var c in Model.Cleaners.OrderBy(x => x.ConfirmationChecker))
```

Hope this helps :)!